# pugixml "extend" element to add value

Tags: c++, xml, pugixml

I trying to set the value of an element, regulary when the element looks like this `<element></element>` I just do this :

```
pugi::xml_node node = xmlBase.child("element");
pugi::xml_node nodechild = node.first_child();
nodechild.set_value(this->elementValue);
```

But, when I have an element looking like this:

```
<element />
```

this wont work.. i tried using this before the "set_value" row

```
if(nodechild == NULL)
{
    nodechild = node.append_child();
}
```

but this will create a new element within that element, and I dont want to do this,

Perhaps my fist approach is even wrong?
how do you properly set the value of the element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like the Solution is to do this:

```
nodechild = node.append_child(pugi::node_pcdata);
```

this will create a child thats only plain text within the element

Comment: That's correct; as per http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/manual/dom.html#node_pcdata text inside the elements has its own node; <element/> has no child nodes (<element></element> also has none; <element>x</element> has a PCDATA child), so you need to explicitly append the node with the correct type.